# second and third menu have a left margin

Tags: html, css, menu

Why does the second and third submenu expand start from another position than the first two menus? I want every menu to start at det same place and end at the same place with a width of 95%.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
// css
#menu {
  width: 960px;
  height: 40px;
  clear: both;
}

ul#nav {
  float: left;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background: #0066ff;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;  
}

ul#nav li {
  display: inline;
}

ul#nav li a {
  float: left;
  font: bold 1.1em arial,verdana,tahoma,sans-serif;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #880000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 30px;
  background: #0066ff;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;     
}

/* APPLIES THE ACTIVE STATE */
ul#nav .current a, ul#nav li:hover > a  {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #330000;
  background: #abcdef;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px; 
}

/* THE SUBMENU LIST HIDDEN BY DEFAULT */
ul#nav  ul {
  display: none;
}

/* WHEN THE FIRST LEVEL MENU ITEM IS HOVERED, THE CHILD MENU APPEARS */
ul#nav li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  width: 95%;
  height: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 40px 0 0 0;
  background: #abcdef;  
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; 
}

ul#nav li:hover > ul li a {
  float: left;
  font: bold 1.1em arial,verdana,tahoma,sans-serif;
  line-height: 45px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #110000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 30px 0 0;
  background: #abcdef; 
}

ul#nav li:hover > ul li a:hover {
  color: #120000;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="menu">


<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 1 Submenu item 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 1 Submenu item 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 1 Submenu item 3</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>

<li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 2 Submenu item 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 2 Submenu item 2</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2 Submenu 2 item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2 Submenu 2 item 2</a>

  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2 Submenu 2 item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2 Submenu 2 item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 2 Submenu item 3</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>

<li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 3 Submenu item 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 3 Submenu item 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu 3 Submenu item 3</a></li>
 </ul>
</li> 
</ul>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to change the margins and other values to, but cant find it. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the position of the ul element is absolute, I added left: 0 to it, which keeps them all opening in the same position.

Here's the bit I changed:

```
ul#nav li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  left: 0; /* added to keep positioning the same */
  max-width: 960px; /* set the max width of the submenu(s) */
  width: 100%; /* set to 100% */
  height: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 40px 0 0 0;
  background: #abcdef;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

And here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L0xL2zL0/1/) of it.

**Edit**:

To make everything work the way you want you'll have to change a few more things, you'll want to set all margins in the body to be 0. Also, again the width is set to 960px if you want to adjust that to be smaller adjust that pixel size instead of using percentages.

```
body {
  margin: 0; /* to remove margins */
}

#menu {
  width: 960px;
  height: 40px;
  clear: both;
}

ul#nav {
  float: left;
  width: 100%; /* this needs to be 100% if you want to adjust the size, adjust above where it says 960px */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background: #0066ff;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

ul#nav li {
  display: inline;
}

ul#nav li a {
  float: left;
  font: bold 1.1em arial, verdana, tahoma, sans-serif;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #880000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 30px;
  background: #0066ff;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}


/* APPLIES THE ACTIVE STATE */

ul#nav .current a,
ul#nav li:hover > a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #330000;
  background: #abcdef;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}


/* THE SUBMENU LIST HIDDEN BY DEFAULT */

ul#nav ul {
  display: none;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* needed to help margins */
}


/* WHEN THE FIRST LEVEL MENU ITEM IS HOVERED, THE CHILD MENU APPEARS */

ul#nav li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  left: 0; /* added to keep positioning the same */
  max-width: 960px; /* set the max width of the submenu(s) */
  width: 100%; /* set to 100% */
  height: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 40px 0 0 0;
  background: #abcdef;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

ul#nav li:hover > ul li a {
  float: left;
  font: bold 1.1em arial, verdana, tahoma, sans-serif;
  line-height: 45px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #110000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 30px 0 0;
  background: #abcdef;
}

ul#nav li:hover > ul li a:hover {
  color: #120000;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

And here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L0xL2zL0/2/) of the updated changes.

Comment: Yes, that solves a part of the problem. But at det right side the width still changes, and looks different as you go down the submenus

Comment: @Carl oops, sorry I missed that. I edited my answer with updated CSS to address this. Basically with the width set to 95% it was only doing 95% of the parent element, thereby getting 5% smaller each level down causing the right edge to decrease that amount each time.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But I am still not totally satisfied. Because the width of the submenus is bigger/wider than the topmenu. I want every menu to be the same. Is this possible?

Comment: and when I minimize the window the difference between the widths of the submenus are bigger

Answer (score 0):

[**SEE THE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/388hfase/2/)

Here's the CSS you need to add/update:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

ul#nav {
  width: 100%;
}

ul#nav ul {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul#nav li:hover > ul {
  left: 0;
  max-width: 960px;
  width: 100%; 
}
```